# Blackberry code signing spam

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

I am an Android developer just getting my feet wet with BlackBerry. I am trying to port an Android app that I have created to BB. In doing this I've started using this command:

```
Backlight.enable(true);
```

This command required that I obtain code signing keys and start signing my application. 
It seems to me that I have to resign this application each and every time I make any change to the code. When I go through the signing process I am told that there are 76 files which require signing. Each time signing is complete I receive 76 individual emails telling me that the signing completed successfully. Which means while developing I am going to be receiving several hundred if not thousands of these emails every day.

My question is: Is this really how the workflow is supposed to be? Am I not doing something correctly in my signing process that is making me sign every time I want to run new version?

It seems completely ridiculous how I am doing it now, so I am hoping I have just overlooked something and it is not actually this bad.

Comment: Have you thought about just not enabling the backlight until you're ready to release?

Comment: I think that is actually the route that I am going to take, now that I know how much of a pain in the neck this process is. Up until today though I didn't have my signing keys, so I wasn't sure if my backlight command was going to work properly. So I had to test it with a few different variations.

Comment: In that case preprocessor statements could be useful as you get more of these, e.g. //#ifdef testmode http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've setup a rule in my gmail account that bins these emails before they can notify me. I recommend using an email account that allows you to do similar. There is no way I know of to get RIM to stop sending them to you.

GMAIL RULE:

```
Matches: from:(websigner@ws-smtp.rim.net)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Mark as read, Delete it
```

The only way I know to avoid signing the code (when restricted API's are present) is to use the BB simulator. I appreciate it's better to test on a device, but I think in many situations the simulator is good enough so I usually use a combination of the two.

Also someone has setup a twitter account that reports the status of the RIM code signing servers. Username: SigningServer, if you stick with it you will now and again encounter outages, another reason for having the simulator handy.

Comment: Yup I set up a 'Rule' in my exchange to make these skip inbox and go to blackberry spam folder. I was just hoping maybe I set something up wrong and this was not the permanent solution. Thanks for the info!